# Map in Map Map.Clear() error

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

```
void destroy()
{
    AList::const_iterator a;
    for(a = AList.begin(); a != AList.end();)
    {
        if(!a->second.BList.empty())
            a->second.BList.clear();//will give error if not mutable
    }
}
typedef std::map<unsigned int,int> bmap;
typedef std::map<unsigned int,someStruct> Alist;
typedef struct someStruct
{
    float x,y,z;
    bmap BList; //needs to be mutable for Blist.clear() above.
    //mutable bmap BList; //<---like this
} someStruct;
```

I only chanced across mutable as an option in a similar but not the same question. My question is am I doing the right thing, or if there are any pitfalls in doing so? Thank you for your help in advance.

```
//error given: (if otherwise not mutable)
// error: passing 'const AList' as 'this' argument of 'void std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::clear() [with _Key = unsigned int, _Tp = int, _Compare = std::less<unsigned int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, int> >]' discards qualifiers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `iterator` instead of `const_iterator`, if your intent is to call `clear`. `const_iterator` is for cases where you are calling only `const` member functions.

Using `mutable` is not appropriate for this situation. Only mark member variables `mutable` if they are not part of the object's visible state, e.g., cached data.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I think I was staring at the code too long and took for granted the iterator.
I am not quite sure what you meant by "visible state". I am not in anyway familiar with mutable, its just that another post used it to solve something that was const, and it just worked for me, but of course that's why i asked this question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried, putting simple `iterator` ?

```
AList::iterator a;
```

`const_iterator` doesn't allow the members to be modifiable (some what like `const` in normal context).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I took Chris' answer, because it was only slightly clearer. :)

Answer (score 0):

The code given by you is not correct. `destroy` should have been a const-member of class, but you have shown it as global function. Since/If `destroy` is const method, `clear` wouldn't work on it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Destroy was a member of a class, and destroy shouldn't be constant in my case, but i accept it was unclear. However the problem was solved as outlined above. Thanks :)